# Comparing values in a list to create a matching list

Tags: python

I have list in this style:

```
[ [x,y,z] , [x1,y1,z1] , [...]].
```

My problem is that I want to make a new list with somehow sorted values. In a first step I want to make a list where for all the same x and y I have the corresponding z values. Here is a example:

raw data:

```
[[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,2,7],[2,2,10],[2,2,11]]
```

processed data:

```
[[1,2 [5,6,7]],[2,2[10,11]]
```

In the final step I would like to have  list like that:

```
[[x values], [y values], [z minimum values], [z length]]
[[1,2],[2,2],[5,10],[3,2]]
```

First I tried to make a list with all possible combinations of x and y (its not infinite in my data) but then I thought that just comparing the consecutive values would be easier, but I didnt figure it out.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` should be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting out, it would be useful to break the problem into smaller problems and tackle it bit by bit.

For the first step, the easiest approach might be to first collect the information using a dictionary.

You go through all triplets in the original list and create a dictionary where each key is a distinct (x, y) pair. Values would be z values from the list.

```
import collections

l = [[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,2,7],[2,2,10],[2,2,11]]
mapping = collections.defaultdict(list)

for x, y, z in l:
    mapping[(x, y)].append(z)

# >> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {(1, 2): [5, 6, 7], (2, 2): [10, 11]})
```

We are using a `defaultdict`, with a `list` constructor, so that we don't have to manually check if an items already exists in the list.

Now that we have a dictionary, it is easy to build the first list. We just have to go through all keys and values and create a proper list format.

```
intermediate_list = [[x, y, zs] for (x, y), zs in mapping.iteritems()]
# >> [[1, 2, [5, 6, 7]], [2, 2, [10, 11]]]
```

In the third step we can again utilize our dictionary. First entries in the list will be all keys from the dictionary and then we need to keep adding minimum and maximum values.

```
final_list = []
minimums = []
lengths = []

for (x, y), zs in mapping.iteritems():
    final_list.append([x, y])
    minimums.append(min(zs))
    lengths.append(len(zs))

final_list.append(minimums)
final_list.append(lengths)

# >> [[1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 10], [3, 2]]
```